# Phaser Sprite for joint between two bodies

Tags: box2d, phaser-framework

I am using `Phaser 2.4.4` in combination with the `Box2D` plugin to produce a simple slingshot game (think Angry Birds). The issue I'm running into is in defining a Sprite for the slingshot's rubber band.

In its simplest form this Sprite would be a rectangle that changes its width and angle so that one end remains fixed to the slingshot's pellet (which is draggable by the user), and the other end remains fixed to a immovable point on the slingshot.

This is solvable by manually coding some update logic to calculate the angle and width on each frame based on the location of the pellet, but this seems like a heavy brute-force solution. I'm wondering if anybody can point me to some native functionality in Phaser which would make this easier.

The problem seems to be that the rubber band is not really a "body", but more like a "joint" between two bodies. And as far as I can tell, Phaser only seems to support attaching Sprites to bodies, not to joints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I apparently answered my own question. The "brute force approach" is actually pretty simple. Just need to define a `Phaser.Point` object on the rubber band Sprite to remember its starting position and then define a `stretch()` method that is called on update, which uses `Point.distance()` and `Point.angle()`. Like this:

```
stretch(pellet) {
  let pellet_distance = this.start_pos.distance(pellet);
  let pellet_angle = this.start_pos.angle(pellet);

  this.width = pellet_distance + pellet.width; 
  this.rotation = pellet_angle;
}
```